# How do I edit the default start page in Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I really like the default Firefox start page, but, as a (pseudo)web developer, I want to tweak a few things. Is it possible to edit the start page **without** changing it entirely?

I'm talking about this page, by the way:
[image: firefox]

If it matters, I'm on Windows 7.

Also, if you hit `View Source` on that page, it seems to reference a `.xhtml` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Aurora\browser\omni.ja!\chrome\browser\content\browser\abouthome\aboutHome.xhtml`, however, I can't open the `omni.ja!` file.

#### My question can be one of two things:

1) How would you open the `omni.ja` file to get its contents?

2) How could I edit that page using `about:config`?

Comment: Might be helpful - http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/where-is-the-firefox-home-page-stored-at.73074/

Comment: @ekaj Thanks! However, that's not quite what I wanted. The HTML of the page uses some dependent variables to render it, so simply changing the location using that and copying the code, it wouldn't render properly. Thanks anyways, though

Comment: I'm aware of what you want, but I don't know how to do it, I've looked for 10 minutes or so - I just thought that might be helpful.

Comment: @ekaj Thanks anyways! It's the thought that counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`omni.ja` is a specially crafted zip file. Change its extension to zip and Windows will let you extract its contents. Keep in mind that some zip utilities, like 7zip, will choke not recognizing it as a valid zip file.

Comment: to refine the comment of paa it is not zip . To be precise it is short form of jar file of java . You can extract with winrar or few jar extractors out there.

Comment: Wrong, it's a zip file optimized for faster reading than plain zip files

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why 7zip was complaining about it. I'll try that now, and if it works, I'll accept!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_(formerly_omni.jar) please reffer to this . I doubt if mozilla is wrong

Comment: I don't see where it says "it is short form of jar file of java"

Comment: please see this . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format).jar file by itself means a java archive . Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The extension `jar` is used for java archives, but `omni.ja` is not a java archive. You can decompress `omni.ja` and  then compress its contents with any zip tool (including 7zip) and Firefox will start as usual, albeit slightly slower. The same is not true for java archives. Although they are zip files, like `omni.ja`, if you decompress one and just compress its contents with a zip tool you will have problems. `They can also use zip tools to do so; however, the order of entries in the zip file headers is important when compressing, as the manifest often needs to be first`.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked in advanced settings yet?  in the url bar enter about:config  and you will have to agree to a warranty disclaimer. you will then be presented with mozilla firefox's insides, (also how you remove pesky toolbars and homepages)

Comment: Where would it be in `about:config`? I've been there once before editing my search engine, but I haven't looked around too much.

Comment: another way is to make your own custom home page from html and load your home page from the local html file you create.